# How to filter arrays in a JSON by multiple tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering in React a list of images from a Json like this one

```
{
  "images": [
    ["c8483f65-f67f-48d9-a0f8-78da8f66115d", "Image 0", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/2293625f8b5e74478e51434fbbe158b43f17b04f.jpg", ["servant", "shoes"]],
    ["4d22a5b7-079d-4f1c-9eba-570165c1f6b1", "Image 1", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/4cc3559217012e477a674862f13d4ac533733cff.jpg", ["screw", "restaurant"]],
    ["acd3b528-3c56-41c9-a2bc-6094a55e21be", "Image 2", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/6e817b4032beccbd7a3c93dc3b7e1f771e15aaec.jpg", ["cub", "relation"]],
    ["fca42de6-0eb1-4449-ab91-61b558c7b972", "Image 3", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/d14e008e2aa18bcae592c5e16968050e7ca5ed43.jpg", ["condition", "butter"]],
    ["73fa77dd-6ec6-4f4d-a991-1bc6b59fb5fa", "Image 4", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/2ca352bdf59566dbffef94724a192713f8970437.jpg", ["zoo", "wheel"]],
    ["34982d91-d537-4bc0-a481-028879a22c27", "Image 5", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/6e7e3e6a60dcd4b27ac6940a8f44893010f171e4.jpg", ["way", "chess"]],
    ["4bdc55e4-937a-4208-aff3-981776a2404e", "Image 6", "https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/20f3c14be166a24376e98b81f9464e153e6ece55.jpg", ["country", "smell"]],
{
```

I fetch this data from the JSON and pass it as props to a React component named ImageList that Maps and renders them as below

```
class ImageList extends React.Component{
    render(){
    console.log(this.props.images)
        var mappedImages = this.props.images.map(
        (img,index) => {
            return (
            <Img className = 'img' key = {img[0]} alt = {img[1]} src = {img[2]} tags = {img[3]}/>
            );
          } 
        );

        return(
            <div className = "imageList">
                {mappedImages}

           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can i filter this images by name and / or multiple tags.
The second element of each array is the name of the image and the last is an array of tags.

Comment: Use the `filter`, or, if you're using `redux`, `reselect` is a nice alternative.

Comment: Filter how? Based on which properties?

Comment: by any of the tags in the last element of the "image" arrays, and i mean they could be every number of tags

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check each individual image against your search and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if any of the tags of a given image match those in the search:

```js
const images = [
  ["Image 0", ["servant", "shoes"]],
  ["Image 1", ["screw", "restaurant"]],
  ["Image 2", ["cub", "relation"]],
  ["Image 3", ["condition", "butter"]],
  ["Image 4", ["zoo", "wheel"]],
  ["Image 5", ["way", "chess"]],
  ["Image 6", ["country", "smell"]],
];

const searchName = "Image 3";
const searchTags = ["cub", "country"];

console.log(images.filter(([name, tags]) => {
  // With .find:
  // return name === searchName || tags.find(tag => searchTags.includes(tag));
  
  // With .some:
  return name === searchName || tags.some(tag => searchTags.includes(tag));
}).map(image => image[0]).join(', '));
```

If you need to take into account things like case insensitivity, ignoring spaces and line breaks or just taking into account more fields into your search, you could add a "search" property to those images, which you would only compute, probably in a service, and then use a single [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) inside [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const images = [
  ["Image 0", ["servant", "shoes"]],
  ["Image 1", ["screw", "restaurant"]],
  ["Image 2", ["cub", "relation"]],
  ["Image 3", ["condition", "butter"]],
  ["Image 4", ["zoo", "wheel"]],
  ["Image 5", ["way", "chess"]],
  ["Image 6", ["country", "smell"]],
];

const searchName = "Image 3";
const searchTags = ["cub", "country"];

// Generate your search RegExp based on the active filters:
const searchRegExp = new RegExp(`${ searchName }|${ searchTags.join('|') }`.replace(/\s/g, '\\s'), 'i');

console.log(searchRegExp);

// You would do this in the service or in a selector, not inside render,
// so that you only compute it once:

const imagesWithSearchTerm = images.map(image => {
  const [name, tags] = image;
  
  // Concatenate all fields you want to take into account for the search:
  image.push(`${ name }, ${ tags.join(', ') }`);
  
  return image;
});

console.log(imagesWithSearchTerm.filter(image => {
  return searchRegExp.test(image[2]);
}).map(image => image[0]).join(', '));
```

In this simple example, the `RegExp` solution is slower and looks more complex, but if the search logic grows, this might actually be faster and easier to understand/reason about.

Also, your filtering logic should not be inside `render`, as that could introduce some performance issues into your application. You should move that to a service/selector or [use memoization](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-memo-vs-memoize-71f85eb4e1a), either on that whole component or only around the filtering logic.

The first search solution and the former memoization approach would look something like this:

```
const ImageList = React.memo(({
    searchName,
    searchTags,
    images,
}) => {
    const mappedImages = images.filter(([name, tags]) => {
        return name === searchName || tags.some(tag => searchTags.includes(tag));
    }).map(([name, tags, src]) => (
        <Img
            key={ name }
            className="img"
            tags={ tags }
            src={ src }
        />
    ));

    return (
        <div className="imageList">
            { mappedImages }
        </div>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `.filter` before you do your `.map`:

```
// In your example, this variable comes from user input, so it's dynamic and should be passed as `this.props.tags`
const tags = ['servant', 'zoo', 'chess', 'smell'];

const images = this.props.images
  .filter(img => {
    // Add all your filters here
    // only the elements that return `true` here will be passed, all else will be filtered out.
    return img[1] === 'someImageName' && tags.some(img[2].includes);
  })
  .map(img => {
    return (
      <Img className='img' 
           key={img[0]} 
           alt={img[1]} 
           src={img[2]} 
           tags={img[3]}
      />
    );
  });
```

Comment: the problem is that the user could set any number of filters, and i don't know 'a priori' how many and which filters the user will choose, maybe i would need some kind of callback in the filter, i don't know if i explained the problem correctly

Comment: @Kousha i have tested your solution and it throws error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: So you want to filter by a specific tag, i.e. if the tag array has an element, then include it?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou updated it - had a syntax error sorry!

Comment: The user should be able to filter by n tags (other than by name)

Comment: @Syertim can you provide an example? I'm not following how you exactly you want to filter by tags tbh. What do you mean `filter by n tags`?

Comment: @Syertim if you don't know which filters the user will use, how you will be able to write the code?

Comment: @Syertim `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: with "filter by n tags" i mean that the user can for example filter by multiple tags like : 'servant' 'zoo' 'chess' 'smell'....

Comment: Then use the updated example I gave - `img[2].includes(...)`; I updated my answer.

Comment: When you say the `user` can filter by multiple tags, you are implying the user is entering some parameters. So in the answer above, the variable `tags` would be coming from user input, so it's dynamic instead of being static as I have it.